# Disable password expiration while joining AD

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-server-2012

I want to create a local user without password expiration on a Windows Server 2012 VM using a powershell script.

In the moment when the user is created, the machine is not in AD. The problem is, that as soon the machine joins AD, the password expiration of the user is set on true.

My code:

```
net user my_user "password /add
wmic useraccount where "Name='my_user'" set PasswordExpires=false
```

This works but only until the machine joins AD. It seems that the AD join somehow modifies the local users.
How can I prevent this?

Regards Tom

Comment: Do you see any possibly relevant GPOs in `gpresult /r`?

Comment: What prevents you from unchecking password expire in the user's properties page? As soon as you uncheck it, the user will be able to login again. So only if you make the change and the user also logs in at that moment, could there be an issue. This makes me think that the user is made with the password can expire checkbox active, and joining the domain enforces the password policy expiring the account.

Comment: By chance is the Windows Server the domain server?

Comment: I assumed Server 2012 was the domain server given the question

Comment: If the WS2012 is the domain server, then it's impossible, to have "local" accounts.  In order to access the server you would have to use a domain account.  Clients connected to the machine can have local accounts but the AD server itself cannot.  Different polciies can be handled by different OUs

Answer (score 1):

You need another script for after the computer has joined and restarted to set the password settings for no password change.

It cannot all be done in one script because of the workstation changes joining the domain. The resulting user is a different workstation user and new on the domain.

Two scripts will be your solution.